# AWS IAM Fine-Grained Access Control though APIGateway and Lambda

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, access-control

I'm new to AWS, and have inherited an existing project.

The project uses Vue.js as the front-end, and data are stored in DynamoDB. User authentication was done using Cognito, with IAM role attached. Data are retrieved though APIGateway and Lambda from the database, through a different role.

Frontend role

Trusted entities: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "execute-api:Invoke"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Backend role

Trusted Entities:
The identity provider(s) apigateway.amazonaws.com,
The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1493183261000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:GetRecords",
            "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
            "dynamodb:ListStreams",
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/foo",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/bar",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/bar/index/dayKey-captureTime-index"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However, I need to implemented authorization for users, so that I can assign Group to certain users, so they have access to specific items, and restrict access to other items in dynamoDB

I read about IAM Fine-Grained Access Control, but it would not work since users talk to the database through APIGateway, which have access to ALL the data.

Either I can drop APIGateway and Lambda, and let user talk to DynamoDB directly (which seem to be a bad idea, since Lambda does some works to the data, and this approach will make my application too tightly attached to AWS).

Or I can create additional API with different permissions, which doesn't seem like the right approach.

Does anyone have any suggestion? or know a better approach?

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway supports access control down to the Method level. It's hard to dynamically control access to specific items in DDB, but if you're talking about specific, static items, then you could hard code the table/item into the API GW or Lambda layer and control access to that API Method with the API Gateway permissions.

Using the API Gateway access control might force you to adjust/re-design the API a little bit.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Permission",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"           
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage/METHOD_HTTP_VERB/resource-path"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue.

The front-end execute a API gateWay endpoint. Then the API endpoint trigger an lambda function make interaction with database. So actually, if we want to restriction in IAM policy level, we should put restriction in a policy of the function execution role with  element. But the issue, I couldn't find any way to access incoming parameter of a function in policy level to use them in condition.

So it seems that best way is to put a condition in function code(business logic level).

And these docs may help you..

- [The structure of condition in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html)
- [Using Policy condition for fine-grained accessed to DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)
- [Conditions keys (in policy) for a lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awslambda.html#awslambda-policy-keys)